# IntelliSense in Visual Studio doesn't work - only for a specific project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, editor

My Visual Studio 2017 15.6.7 installation doesn't display a red squiggly line under code that has errors. I'm using C++.

This happens only for a specific project in the Solution - for the rest the squiggly lines appear as expected.

I have tried to unload and reload this project, to no avail.

This happens both for header and `.cpp` files. I have validated that the files are part of the project.

Additionaly - it does seem that IntelliSense in general doesn't work properly for this project. The Auto Complete feature (for example, after typing a `->`) does not list the correct options.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: is it a cpp or a header file? Is the file part of the project? Please provide a [mre]

Comment: Do not rely on "squiggly lines" to tell you why something doesn't compile. Sooner or later squiggly lines will not give you a complete picture, and the only thing that's left that you can look at are your C++ compiler's error messages. C++ error messages are legendary for their complexity and obfuscation. If you don't learn how to read an interpret C++ error messages it will be very difficult to write and debug C++ code of any moderate complexity.

Comment: A screenshot would go a long way here..

Comment: I suggest that you ccould check whether there is a code that causes intellisense to stop working in the specific project, such as special characters in a string.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Well, of course I'm able to interpret C++ compiler errors... :)  The squiggly lines are simply a great productivity tool often enabling you to see that something is broken the moment after you wrote it. It's especially useful considering C++ compile times. The main reason to use an IDE as opposed to a simple text editor, is these types of features. Once again, of course not as a replacement to the compiler error output, but as an addition.

Comment: @AlanBirtles It happens both for header and `.cpp` files. And yes, the files are part of the project. Please see updated question. Regarding an example: since it's not really a "code" question, I'm not sure what concrete example I can share here apart from supplying all of the needed details. Can you be more specific? Thank you :)

Comment: well theres obviously something different about the project and/or the code, a [mre] would be the minimal code and project that reproduces the problem